# I felt as if it "was" or "were" grinning at me?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, syntactic-analysis, conjugation, irrealis-were

> A wicked aura around it, I felt as if it **was** grinning at me

or

> A wicked aura around it, I felt as if it **were** grinning at me

?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime The question is the same, but the answer there is not really on point. It doesn't mention "as if" at all, but talks about two different ways to use "if" (forming a conditional versus a counterfactual).

Comment: @Barmar it may be true that the linked question doesn't yet have an ideal answer, but the questions are certainly duplicates of each other, so one should be marked as a duplicate. I think it makes sense to point this one to the older question.  I agree with you that the linked question could still benefit from a thorough and clear answer that addresses the specific concern.

Comment: The purpose of closing a question as a duplicate is because there's already an answer there, so there's no point in answering it again. If the other question is the same, but there's no good answer there, how does it help anyone who wants an answer to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need a subject in your sentence.  I would go with some thing like this : There was a wicked aura around that house; it seemed as if the house smiled at me with a evil grin.

Comment: I mean to use it like this: It was a sunny Sunday afternoon in May when my parents came back home with groceries and I saw the unholy fruit poking out of a paper bag. A wicked aura around it, I felt as if it were grinning at me.

D'you think this is correct?

Comment: You must break up the ideas for clarity. There was a sunny Sunday afternoon in May when my parents came home with an unholy fruit poking out of a paper grocery bag.  The fruit had a wicked aura around it. . . .

Comment: The first clause could be something like "Due to the wicked aura around it, I felt ..."